# mysql query with bash

Tags: mysql, sql, bash

I have a bash script that computes the `md5hash` of every file inside directory recursively and I 
output this into a text file (Column1 -- Hash Column2 -- path of the file). Now I want for each row of column one of the text file ,query the mysql database that contains a table of all hashes, filename. If its present, I want to delete the file. How do I query from a bash script to achieve this? The mysql database contains 2million entries.

```
##!/bin/bash

##BINARIES

MD5DEEP=$(which md5deep)

OPTIONS="-rl"

WORKDIR="/scripts/test"

##CREATE HASH FOR EACH FILES

myhash=`$MD5DEEP $OPTIONS $WORKDIR`

echo "$myhash"
```

The output of the text file is as shown:

f59f1294e66775ef47a28ef0cac8229a  /scripts/test/t1

44d88612fea8a8f36de82e1278abb02f  /scripts/test/eicar.com.txt

Now,I want to compare column1 value of each row of this text file with the database of hashes,if its present then,I want to delete that file.Can somebody please provide some guidance here?

Comment: you may try mysql -e to execute queries on the command line.

Comment: Can you give an example? Like what needs to be added to the script for comparison operations?

Comment: I am sorry, I am not that fluent in bash